# Angular 1.4.8 / JS : create constructor and inherit properties into a 3rd object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**DEV TOOLS**

Angular 1.4.8 & lodash

**QUESTION**

EDIT

To clarify my question:

1. create an object (articles)
2. apply a constructor
3. and then import the properties of a 3rd object, but place it in
   proto folder so I don't end up with a large collection of properties
   in root

As I said my code works but I ask as I come from a more structured language background and the inheritance just feel brittle and messy, but maybe that is JS ES5 ... 6 looks better.

The code below works, but as I’m new to JS I’m wondering if there is better way to build an object (“class”) where I create a consctrutor from data/ keys passed in and then extend my current object with a 3rd object’s properties in a section/folder in proto folder ? The `Extendable()` function that builds the construct and inherits the properties feels ugly.

In the example below :

1. I create an article instance by injecting data and keys. I then
   use the _constructor factory to create a constructor for
   `articleModel`.
2. I then extend the article instance with the properties of 3rd
   object, model (Model Provider), but also want to place them in the `__proto__` folder with the a specific key of “Eloquent”.

example:

```
Extendable
// Extendable constructor properties
__proto__: Extendable
    Eloquent: Object
      // 'Eloquent model' inherited properties
```

CODE:

```
    (function() {
        'use strict';

        _Constructor.$inject = [];
        function _Constructor() {
             function __constructor(data, keys) {
                _.assign(this, _.pick(data, keys));
            }
            return __constructor;
        }

        ArticleModel.$inject = ['model', '_Constructor'];
        function ArticleModel(model, _Constructor) {

            function Extendable(data, keys) {
                _Constructor.call(this, data, keys);
                // This works but NOT pretty. Is there a cleaner or better way to decorate / inherit e.g. is there a ::__parent() method?
                var decorate = Extendable.prototype['Eloquent'] = {};
                // model is a the main model provider
                _.assign(decorate, model);
            }

            Extendable.prototype = Object.create(_Constructor.prototype);
            Extendable.prototype.constructor = Extendable;
            var article = Extendable.prototype;

            article.pleaseWork = function() {
                return 'The JS gods are pleased! move forward 1 test!';
            };

            return Extendable;
        }

        angular.module('article', [

        ])
        .factory('_Constructor', _Constructor)
        .service('article', ArticleModel)

    })();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve here. It sounds like you are trying to create new objects which will also inherit properties from the base object and possibly from 3rd object.

let's assume you have a base object: base = {foo: 1}
Now you have another object: third = {third: 1}
Now we want to create an object that inhierits from base and also have properties from third.

```
var newGuyOnTheBlock = Object.create(base); //creates a new object from base and will have all properties from base
_.extend(newGuyOnTheBlock, third); // now it'll have properties from third and base
```

Comment: Henry that is exactly what I'm trying to do 1. create an object (articles) 2. apply a constructor and import the properties of a 3rd object, but place it in proto folder so I don't end up with a large collection of properties in root. I think I've done what you've suggested in the code above although it is more verbose. I suppose given I come form more structured language background it just feel brittle and messy, but maybe that is JS ES5 ... 6 looks better. Thanks a million

Comment: Just keep in mind this is prototypically inherited/chained.. If base changes later, those changes will also be "propagated" tonewGuyOnTheBlock object.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, which is why in my actual code (not above code) I decorate the universal Model class with the articles model properties so that Model is to all decorating classes articles, images, polls, etc. but I reversed it in this post for brevity sake. I really like JS but somedays it hurts my brain ... lol

Comment: I like how concise js can be.